# Django REST: create CRUD operations for OneToOne Field

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to create basic CRUD operations for OneToOne field. 
The user is not required to set the profile when signing in. How do I create/update/delete profile when needed (assuming the user is already in the DB)?

My models are the default User models from Django REST and:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User)
        location = models.CharField(max_length=50,blank=True)
        title = models.CharField(max_length=80,blank=True)
        #picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='user_imgs', blank=True)
        website = models.URLField(blank=True)
```

My Viewsets are:

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']

class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    filter_fields = ['user_id', 'location', 'title', 'website']
```

And serializes:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        email = serializers.EmailField()
        fields = ('id','username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name')


class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    user_id = serializers.CharField(source='user.id')

    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user_id', 'location','title','website')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I belive you want to restrict the profile creation to the current logged in user. You can filter the queryset of profiles to the current user, this way only that user's profile will be accessible by the logged in user.

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer
    filter_fields = ['id', 'username', 'email', 'first_name', 'last_name']


class UserProfileViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = UserProfile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    filter_fields = ['user_id', 'location', 'title', 'website']

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(UserProfileViewSet, self).get_queryset().filter(
            user=self.request.user)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=user)
```

You make the `user` field read only and is being saved in the above method `perform_create` and assigned always to the current user.

```
class UserProfileSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('user', 'location','title','website')
        read_only_fields = ('user',)
```

Answer (score 2):

It should focus to define `view` how to receive request and process raw data, not the `model` and `serializer` of the field definition.

I give you a CRUD example for basic `User` operation as the reference:

lu = LibraryUser(library_membership_number= '...', user_id = user)

```
class ExampleAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        username = request.query_params.get('username', '')
        user = User.objects.get(username=username)
        return Response(ExampleSerializer(user).data)

    def post(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username', '')
        email = request.data.get('email', '')
        password = request.data.get('password', '')
        user = User.objects.create_user(username=username, email=email, password=password)
        user.save()
        Response({'status': 'ok'}})

    def put(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username', '')
        old_password = request.data.get('old_password', '')
        new_password = request.data.get('new_password', '')
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=old_password)
        if not user:
            return Response({'status': 'fail'}})
        user.set_password(new_password)
        return Response({'status': 'ok'}})

    def delete(self, request):
        username = request.query_params.get('username', '')
        user.objects.get(username=username).delete()
        return Response({'status': 'ok'}})
```

Accord to the example, these are my definitions for each method:

- `GET`: Retrieve the user profile
- `POST`: Create a new user
- `PUT`: Change the user of the password
- `DELETE`: Delete the user

So, it will implement Basic CRUD api for `user` instance.

I hope that it can help you how to design api.

---

If you don't still understand how to operate `model`, I will more introduce the example:

```
class ExampleAPIView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        username = request.query_params.get('username', '')
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=username)
        return Response(ExampleSerializer(userprofile).data)

    def put(self, request):
        username = request.data.get('username', '')
        userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=username)
        if not userprofile :
            return Response({'status': 'fail'}})
        userprofile.location = ...
        userprofile.title = ...
        userprofile.website = ...
        userprofile.save()
        return Response({'status': 'ok'}})
```

Comment: Where is the OneToOne field here?

Comment: @Mike You would refer: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships

Comment: Similarly, we can prove that It's no different.